# I can't find current UIwindow in +(void)load and + (void)initialize method in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to find current window using below code.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:[[CompanyLogo alloc] init]];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:[[CompanyLogo alloc] init]];
```

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The class methods `+(void)load` and `+ (void)initialize` are both called before your view hierarchy has been created. Don't put your code there. Put it in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method instead.

Comment: Duncan, I am creating custom framework classes, That framework initialize automatically when app launch,There are some hidden classes in framework.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:[[CompanyLogo alloc] init]];
```

Comment: That will fail if executed in  `+(void)load` or `+ (void)initialize`

Comment: Sargis Gevorgyan, 
Already I tried that code.It's not wokring

Comment: maybe your CompanyLogo view frame is CGRectZero?
try this code

CompanyLogo *companyLogo = [[CompanyLogo alloc] init];
    companyLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    companyLogo.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:companyLogo];